# dpkg returned an error code (1) while tryint to install python3

Tags: package-management, dpkg, python3

I realize that I have created a major blunder somehow, but I am unable to install `python3` in Ubuntu. I'm getting this error:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `sudo apt-get install pyhton3-all` is:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-dbus
python3-chardet
python3-debian
update-notifier-common
dh-python
python3-commandnotfound
ufw
gconf2
aisleriot
python3-apport
apport
apport-gtk
python3-aptdaemon
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
apturl
python3-checkbox-support
plainbox-provider-resource-generic
plainbox-provider-checkbox
python3-requests
python3-plainbox
checkbox-converged
checkbox-gui
python3-cairo
python3-gi-cairo
gedit
gnome-orca
aptdaemon
gnome-software
hplip-data
ibus-table
language-selector-gnome
nautilus-share
onboard
python3-blinker
python3-bs4
python3-cryptography
python3-cupshelpers
python3-cycler
python3-dateutil
python3-decorator
python3-feedparser
python3-html5lib
python3-httplib2
python3-matplotlib
python3-oauthlib
python3-pandas
python3-pexpect
python3-pil:amd64
python3-pip
python3-pyqt5
python3-reportlab
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

TRhe output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plainbox-provider-checkbox
 nautilus-share
 gconf2
 aisleriot
 update-notifier-common
 system-config-printer-common
 system-config-printer-udev
 system-config-printer-gnome
 apport-gtk
 plainbox-provider-resource-generic
 python3-gi-cairo
 unity-lens-photos
 unity-scope-openclipart
 checkbox-converged
 update-notifier
 aptdaemon
 ubuntu-desktop
 apport
 python3-cupshelpers
 checkbox-gui
 gnome-software
 ubuntu-software
```

Comment: Tried that but not working. Getting error due to may be this:
"python3-all is already the newest version (3.5.1-3). But I am unable to locate python3.5

Comment: The actual errors I believe are above your pasted output, that is summary information the points to actual earlier error messages which are key.  You'll likely find your system will return to workable if you install `python3-minimal`, but give you've somewhat disabled your `apt/aptitude` tools by removing python3 necessary to make them work, you may need to `wget` & `dpkg` install it.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-minimal)